# How to remove notations in xcode appearing after filename?

Tags: xcode, svn, symbols

I'm getting text like A,M,? etc after filename in Xcode. This seems to appear after setting  up project on SVN. How to remove this one?

[image: The following screenshot shows the problem]

Comment: They are there to tell you what has been added (A), modified (M), and not added (?) in source control. You don't want to get rid of them.

Comment: What is I want to remove them?

Comment: If you want to get rid of them, don't use source code control (which is a very bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

They are source control markers

- A = added
- M = modified
- ? = not added

If you dont want them there dont create your project with source control on. Make sure the circled box isnt ticked.

[image]

Creating anything other than a discardable project without source control is going to make you sad one day.

Learn about Source Control and use it if you are serious about development.

Answer (score 0):

These notations basically tells you about project's files current condition at SVN or server that is hosting your code repository and your local repository. For instance, if you add a new file/class/anything you will see 'A', if you do changes in a file you will see 'M'.

If you still want to remove these words in XCode go to :

> file > source control > commit

a window will appear that shows the the changes you have done in files & press commit button. After that these words will be removed.

But wait, before doing anything read about "source control".

Atleast read about these things:

1. Revisions
2. Commits
3. Updates